# Python pass multiple captured REGEX matches to Function

Tags: python, regex

I really appreciate your time.

I am successfully capturing some text between delimiter tags that I specify as *code*.   I have multiple IE:  *code* codes here #1 *code* and then *code* codes here #2 *code*.   I am struggling at getting the REGEX captured code between the *code* markers to my class for formatting.  it always shows up as "codes here #1" over and over.

```
The input text is:

*image1* 
Some More Text here

That's a title pic and there are 2 more enable pictures per page. 
*code* CENTER CODES HERE *code*  Those can be a bit larger. And then     there is more 
code to show *code* MORE CENTER CODE *code*

Paragraph Test
```

Here's what I have capturing the text and then iterating:

```
    replace = CodeboxReplace()
    codeboxRE = re.compile('\*code\*(.*?)\*code\*')
    found = codeboxRE.findall(thisText)
    for item in found:
        thisText = codeboxRE.sub(replace(item), thisText)
```

OK and  then the class CodeboxReplace() looks like this {CODEHERE} is the tag I have in place to be replaced by actual code which was matched between the *code* delimiters:

```
class CodeboxReplace(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.counter = 0

def __call__(self, match):
    self.counter += 1
    .......some not relevant code here................
    codeHereRE = re.compile('{CODEHERE}')
    found = codeHereRE.findall(myCode)
    for item in found:
        myCode = codeHereRE.sub(match, myCode)
    return myCode
```

So fundamentally I want the code snippets captured between the delimiters to replace {CODEHERE}.  But each match always uses only the first capture from the REGEX.

Help!  Thanks!

if you want to see how it renders look at:
http://www.americantechnocracy.com/getArticle

Best Regards,
Tom

Comment: This is not really a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are omitting parts of the code that might show what you want. I think you want the first match of `*code*(...)*code*` to be captured and used to replace the first occurrence of `{CODEHERE}` in a different text in your class. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *sub* method of a regular expression object, replaces **all** non-overlapping, occurrances of the pattern.  So, the first time this is executed:

```
myCode = codeHereRE.sub(match, myCode)
```

it replaces all occurrances of '{CODEHERE}'.  If you only want to replace 1 occurrance, then use the *count* parameter of *sub*:

```
myCode = codeHereRE.sub(match, myCode, count=1)
```

Comment: THANKS!  You got it right -- count=1 does fix the problem.   I had to place it in the calling re.sub though ... ie: thisText = codeboxRE.sub(replace(item), thisText, count=1) solves the problem.  Placing count=1 in the actual replace function doesn't help as the multiple tag substitution is happening in the higher level match...but BIG BIG BIG HELP THANKS SO MUCH